# Geohash graph with Spark-Neo4j-Connector or CAPS

Tags: apache-spark, neo4j, cypher

Is that possible with neo4j-spark-connector to create a geohash graph ?

I've been able to do that with LOAD CSV in neo4j ,but now i want to do it with spark.

my data have two ***GEOHASH*** for each row : one for pickup and another for dropoff=>i want to :

1) connect the pickup and drop off with the relationship TRIP

2) a drop off can be a pickup for another trip

3) merge the creation of nodes

with **LOAD CSV** i have done this:

```
 load csv from "file:///green_data.csv" as line 

 MERGE(p:HashNode {geohash: line[20]}) ON CREATE set p.pickup=True ,p.timehash=line[21] ON MATCH set p.pickup=True, p.timehash=line[21] 

 MERGE(d:HashNode {geohash: line[22]}) ON CREATE set d.dropoff=True,d.timehash=line[23] ON MATCH set d.dropoff=True,d.timehash=line[23] 

 MERGE (p)-[:trip{VendorID:line[0]}]->(d)
```

[image: geohash graph]

Comment: I get a solution for this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51974270/geohash-neo4j-graph-with-spark)